# SSRS 2012 Bar chart spacing- and horizontal names

Tags: reporting-services

I am using ssrs 2012. How can I modify the margin between the vertical axis and my bars  ?
Also, how can I increase the spacing between the bars?
Finally, how do I modify the hortizontal axis labels?
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the spacing between the columns you need to use the `PointWidth` property.

This can be found by clicking on the series in the chart, and looking at the properties. It can be found under the Custom Attributes subgroup.  PointWidth is normally defaulted to 0.8. Reducing this value increases the spacing between the columns.

How do you want to "modify the hortizontal axis labels". What would you like them to be modified to?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Pointwidth didn't give me the desired results so I added 2 dummy values to my query with value 0. This gave me the desired effect.

Comment: I want the horizontal axis labels to be displayed as http://s28.postimg.org/91s62p8h9/goodchart.png and not like it is now http://s18.postimg.org/5xddbktgp/badgraph.gif

Comment: How have you coded this up? As one series or 3 because that second image looks... interesting 

Comment: The simplest way to display three columns all with their own label is to have them in a single series rather than trying to layer the three series on top of each other.  It would be tidiest to do this combination in the SQL behind the dataset.

Comment: Jonnus I am not sure what you mean. Can you please give me an example?